# How to convert .mov file stored or captured in our iOS device to .mp4 format?

Tags: ios, video

I am developing the application, and the application works fine while executing on ios device but while playing the video uploaded from application in Android device the format .mov isn't supportive.

I have the code which works fine but need the video in .mp4 format

```
-(void)openLibrary
{
    cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [cameraUI setDelegate:self];

    [cameraUI setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    [cameraUI setAllowsEditing:YES];
    cameraUI.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                                   usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                                   UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {

    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil))
        return NO;


    cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // Displays a control that allows the user to choose movie capture
    cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;

    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

    [controller presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
    return YES;
}
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // Handle a movie capture

    if (CFStringCompare (( CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        NSUserDefaults *def =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
        videoPath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/xyz.mov",docDir];


        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath))
        {
            NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
            NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
            [videoData writeToFile:videoPath atomically:NO];

            [def setValue:videoPath forKey:@"videoPath"];

        }
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];
        CMTime duration = playerItem.duration;
        float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
        NSLog(@"seconds : %f",seconds);
        if (seconds > 10) {
            [def removeObjectForKey:@"videoPath"];
            _lblVideo.hidden = TRUE;
            [self.view makeToast:@"Select video which is less than 10 seconds" duration:2.0 position:@"center"];

        }
        else
        {
            _lblVideo.hidden = FALSE;
            NSLog(@"Length is not greater than 10");
            [self.view makeToast:@"Word is ready for posting" duration:2.0 position:@"center"];
        }
    }

}
```

Well i am looking for a good solution not the extension change solution that doesn't work at all.

Comment: May be this would help http://www.axllent.org/docs/video/mencoder-for-iphone-android/

Answer (score 0):

when u save your recorded video then change manually .mp4 as following

//your loaca directory

```
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* mp4FilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"recordedVideo.mp4"];
```

Comment: thats exactly i did and wasn't working as you can read the last line of my question...but thanks for the reply...Try to make it worth not a suggestion without any worth